# Android 2.2: best way to read small blocks of binary data from big files?

Tags: android, performance, memory-management, binaryfiles

I'm developing for Android 2.2.

Things put to res and assets are compressed in the APK by default unless their extension indicates that they're already compressed (mp3, png). Moreover, before Android 2.3, to assets, you could only put uncompressed files of size less than 1 MB.

## Question 1:

if I put a 1.5MB binary file to res/raw, and my program refers to it with its standard Android ID (R.raw.....), then will the system pull the **whole file into memory**? Since the 1.5MB is stored in a compressed way, I suppose it must. This is unpleasant because it is possible that the program only needs 1KB of data to be loaded from a given file offset. This can have a serious impact on app performance/speed.

I see two solutions:

1. (hack) Use mp3 or png extensions; but I am not sure this allows memory-efficient access after all (i.e. inputstream.skipbytes, etc.)
2. After the installation, at the first start of the app, the app will copy the files to its own writable working folder (in SD card). Since this point, it will always access the files from there instead of the R.raw... way. Therefore, the sequential read will work for sure, i.e. the memory usage will be no more than the actual data read from the specified file offset (apart from temporary read buffers used by inputstream.seek implementation, which are well-optimized i.e. small I suppose).

## Question 2:

what is the best way of reading binary data memory-efficiently, from big files? I don't want to split my big files into many small ones unless that's the only way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with #2 solution and then would use `RandomAccessFile` to avoid linear access.

Comment: I can optimize my consecutive reads to be sequential (with no effort, due to program semantics), by the way. I.e. after opening the FileInputStream, I can solve that it always reads with increasing offset, there is no need to seek backwards. In such a case, FileInputStream (which does not have seek) is suitable, because I can solve all seek via skipBytes(). Does RandomAccessFile have any benefit over FileInputStream in this case? (Perhaps .seek is better than skipBytes, as it uses underlying OS functions instead of reading through the whole file?)

Comment: From the implementation (see http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch#cZwlSNS7aEw/libcore/luni/src/main/java/java/io/FileInputStream.java&exact_package=android&q=FileInputStream&type=cs&l=308) it looks like `skip()` is implemented via seeking too. So its probably a good idea to stick to `FileInputStream` in your case.

Answer (score 1):

I also would to opt for solution #2, but instead of using random access file,  I would use java.nio.MappedByteBuffer - this way you will get fast  random access with byte buffer semantic.

Comment: Sounds good, but since I'll need typed reading (readInt() etc.) from the bytes as well, and I won't need writing, I think FileInputStream/RandomAccessFile is more suitable. Considering performance, I suppose that if RandomAccessFile is faster than FileInputStream, then RandomAccessFile should be as fast as MappedByteBuffer (just with a different mechanism).

Comment: Not sure.  Getting primitive  from byte buffer is just a wrapper method call - reaaly fast and without overhead imposed by stream ( but it has to be aligned and you have to take care of byte order)